# Variable not getting defined

Tags: javascript, html

One of my event’s variables isn’t getting defined.

The `title` variable isn’t getting defined so I think I made a mistake.

```js
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('item-button')

for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i]
  
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
  var title = storeitem.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerHTML
  
  console.log('title')
}
```

```html
<div class="store-item">
  <span class="product-name">CPU 1</span>
  <img class="cpu-image" src="Images/CPU-1.jpg">
  <div class="product-details">
    <span class="item-price">$229.99</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary item-button" role="button">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `storeitem`. Did you mean `shopItem`? The error message is very clear: _“`ReferenceError`: `storeitem` is not defined”_. Also, `console.log('title')` has nothing to do with your `title` variable. Please use `console.log(event.target.closest(".store-item").querySelector(".product-name").textContent);` instead.

Comment: `'title'` does not hold the value of the variable `title`. When you put `title` inside double quote marks(`""` ) or  single quote marks(`''` ), it does not play a role as a variable anymore, it is a simple string. Take a look at [JavaScript variables](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp). Also see [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). To print a variable, let's say `title` you should do `console.log(title)`. No quotes. Or to be more descriptive `console.log({ title })`, `console.log('title', title)`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code. you need that `shopItem`  as discribe above by Mr.Sebastian Simon and Mr.haggbart.

```js
var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('item-button')

for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
  var button = addToCartButtons[i]
  button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
}

function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target
 
  var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement

  // error here 'storeitem' variable is defined.
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerHTML
  
  console.log('title')
  console.log(title)  // you means title varible
}
```

```html
<div class="store-item">
  <span class="product-name">CPU 1</span>
  <img class="cpu-image" src="Images/CPU-1.jpg">
  <div class="product-details">
    <span class="item-price">$229.99</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary item-button" role="button">ADD TO CART</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addToCartClicked(event) {
  var button = event.target
  var shopItem  = button.parentElement.parentElement
  var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('product-name')[0].innerHTML
  console.log(title)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it solves the problem.